# laravel livewire hosting linux server image not uploading

Tags: laravel-livewire, image-upload

I am using Laravel 8 with livewire and trying to upload image in hosting Linux server giving me error. But in Localhost happening properly no error occur.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `tmpfile()` is disable on the linux server for security reasons. You don't see this error on your local server because `tmpfile()` is not disabled there.

You can check which functions are disabled by using:

```
var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));
```

or open the php.ini file and look for:

```
# list of function to disable globally #
disable_functions=tmpfile
```